# Flask-PageDown and MathJax

Tags: python, flask, markdown, mathjax, pagedown

I managed to implement `PageDown` in my `Flask` app via [Flask-PageDown](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flask-pagedown/), following instructions [here](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/flask-pagedown-markdown-editor-extension-for-flask-wtf).

That works fine, but mathematical expressions (`MathJax`) of the type:

`$$ .... $$`

are not rendered in the previewer via such an extension.

Note that my main template contains the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML"></script>
```

Has someone an idea of how to tackle this ? Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 1):

It's said that you want to use the MATHJAX in your flask app just as Octopress did, right?

Maybe you need this one: [python-markdown-math](https://github.com/mitya57/python-markdown-math), which is recommended by [python-markdown](https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown/wiki/Third-Party-Extensions).

Hopes it will help you. Gook luck.

Comment: not all ... I'd like to have `pagedown` correctly showing `mathjax`.