# How to migrate MathJax with Flask-PageDown?

Tags: javascript, python, html, markdown, mathjax

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29306242/5399734) when trying to use MathJax on my own website. An extension called `python-markdown-math` is suggested by the only answer. However, their [document](https://github.com/mitya57/python-markdown-math) is not very comprehensive for me. Also, it seems that `python-markdown-math` does rendering on server-side, while I want client-side rendering.

My question is: How, **exactly**, to migrate MathJax with Flask-PageDown? By "migrate", I mean rendering notations by Mathjax just-in-time in the preview field of Flask-PageDown. [This](https://kerzol.github.io/markdown-mathjax/editor.html) is an example showing what I want to get.

Here is what I've tried ([fiddle version](https://jsfiddle.net/efkmpw4o/3/)):

```js
f = function() {
  if (typeof flask_pagedown_converter === "undefined")
    flask_pagedown_converter = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter().makeHtml;
  var textarea = document.getElementById("flask-pagedown-body");
  var preview = document.getElementById("flask-pagedown-body-preview");
  textarea.onkeyup = function() {
    preview.innerHTML = flask_pagedown_converter(textarea.value);
  }
  textarea.onkeyup.call(textarea);
}
if (document.readyState === 'complete')
  f();
else if (window.addEventListener)
  window.addEventListener("load", f, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
  window.attachEvent("onload", f);
else
  f();

var textarea = document.getElementById("flask-pagedown-body");

function update_mathjax() {
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
    script;
  script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/x-mathjax-config";
  script[(window.opera ? "innerHTML" : "text")] =
    "MathJax.Hub.Config({\n" +
    "  tex2jax: { inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\\\(','\\\\)']] }\n" +
    "});";
  head.appendChild(script);
  script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = "http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML";
  head.appendChild(script);
};

textarea.addEventListener("onkeyup", update_mathjax, false);
```

```html
<head>
  <title>
    Test
  </title>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="flask-pagedown">
    <textarea class="form-control flask-pagedown-input" id="flask-pagedown-body" name="body" required></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="flask-pagedown-preview" id="flask-pagedown-body-preview"></div>

  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pagedown/1.0/Markdown.Converter.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pagedown/1.0/Markdown.Sanitizer.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you add a live sample page?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Since the html files are created by a template engine(Jinja2), and the markdown-to-html conversion is done at the backend, I think it would be very difficult to create a live example describing my problem...

Comment: The way you use MathJax sets your page up for client-side rendering, so it should contain whatever input markup you use. That's all that plugin does iiuc. You could use mathjax-node for server side rendering but that's a different question.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Question updated. Basically, I want to re-run the relevant javascript code for MathJax rendering whenever a `texture.onkeyup` event happens.

Comment: Have you read http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/advanced/typeset.html ?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Thank for the link. I find it *super* helpful!

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.